# Whats the advantage of single target neural network over multi target neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, multi-output

So right now I have made 2 neural networks to predict x and y coordinates separately. One for x, and one for y. I'm looking for a reason to backup my assignment. I have search for this and most of the results only shows the advantage of multi target without showing the disadvantage of it or stating the advantage of single target neural network.

Is there any reason or advantage of why single target neural network is better than the multi target? And is there any paper or academic research or any source for that?

Comment: In my opinion multitarget would be better because you would be able to share weights and connections rather than doing two separate neural networks

Answer (score 1):

I also would tend to say that a single target network has not much advantages. Just consider you had a setting with three target classes predicted by three networks, theoretically thinking, you could kind of glue the three networks together to get one network with the same outcome.
So what I would reason from that is, that if one network has sufficient weights and output neurons it should be able to learn whatever separate networks can learn.
On the other hand it will be faster to learn one network, because it can share weights.

I think there is a nother aspect that makes multi-target networks more powerful. This is that your loss-function can look at all targets at the same time. So the training result is not necessarily relying on the absolute value of the output, but can consider the confidence on other targets as well. E.g. if you do multi-class classification, you can use the soft-max function (as used very often). The result of this is that the classification is ignoring the exact values but choses the highes ranked class as the result. With several single-target networks you would have to select your output activation function very well (e.g. sigmoid instead of relu) and that could probably lead to inaccuracies.

So to sum up this second point: the multi-target solution leaves you more room to tailor your loss function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly I can't change the code anymore so wish me luck that my lecturer wont fail me

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your assignment.